# Side effects of using Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization

Reviewing server logs I encountered `NotSerializableException` for a domain object during some RMI cache transfer function. I noticed that a domain object doesn't implement `Serializable` interface; however I am a bit sceptical about implementing `Serializable` as I have no idea about its possible side effects. Would it break at some point?

If there are no side effects, why all the objects are not `Serializable` by their own?

Comment: What would happen if all objects were serializable, and you serialized a `FileOutputStream` or a `Socket`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implementing `Serializable` has no side-effects ... apart from the obvious one of making the serialization mechanism *consider* serializing it.

(Of course, that fact that you `implement` the `Serializable` interface doesn't necessarily mean that serialization will work.  For example, if your class has instance fields that are not serializable, and those fields are not declared as `transient`, then the normal serialization mechanism will fail.)

> If there are no side effects why all the objects are not Serializable by their own?

One reason is that some objects have state that cannot be captured and represented by serialization.  Examples include all kinds of Streams that are connected to data sources or sinks outside of the JVM, Java threads, and Java processes.

A second reason is that (arguably) the programmer should decide whether it is *appropriate* for a class to be serializable.  Examples where it might be inappropriate include classes that hold sensitive information or classes whose internals are liable to change ... making deserialization problematic<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - It is possible to deal with this, to a degree, but the programmer may want to say "I don't want to be forced to deal with this" ... for a class the he / she thinks should not be serialized.</sup>